# Keras/TensorFlow: What is the order of the weight tensor dimensions of a convolutional layer?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

In `channels_last` format, the shape of the data tensor is `(batch_size, height, width, channels)` and the shape of the weight tensor is apparently (see reference 2) `(rows, cols, input_depth, output_depth)`.

In `channels_first` format, the shape of the data tensor is `(batch_size, channels, height, width)` and the shape of the weight tensor is what?

I've looked high and low for the answer to that question. When I run my code and use `model.get_weights()` to get the weight and bias tensors, it appears that the format of the weight tensors is the same in `channels_first` as in `channels_last`. Yet, when I output the weight tensors to a file and read them back into my C/C++ code which is hand-crafted and doesn't use TensorFlow, it doesn't appear to be working. The results are numerically nonsensical. Maybe there is some other problem, but I would like to obtain a definitive answer to this question.

BTW, the reason I'm switching between `channels_last` and `channels_first` is that I need to be able to develop my code on a CPU machine and then run large training sessions on a GPU machine.

Any help is appreciated.

References:

[Data tensor shape is explained here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)

[Weight tensor shape is partially explained here.](https://keras.io/api/layers/constraints/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer in source code of TF/keras [`keras/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py#L186-L187), where `data_format=channels_first or data_format=channels_last` is working when forward calculation, but in weight definition, the kernel shape is kept as:

```py
kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (input_channel // self.groups, self.filters)
```

So, it makes you find the weight format is same in `channels_first` or `channels_last` by `model.get_weights()`。

In detail, [convolution op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d8ce9f9c301d021a69953134185ab728c1c248d3/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py) is ultimately performed by `conv1d`, `conv2d`, `conv3d`, etc., in `gen_nn_ops` which defined and conducted by C/C++. Each of these operation need receive `data_format` to adjust inputs but not kernels (weights/filters).

Comment: Thank you for your answer though I'm not sure I really understand the explanation as I don't understand the code. What is the dimension of kernel_shape? It appears to be 2-D. But, the weight tensor is 4-D, so what is the relationship of the kernel_shape to the weight tensor?

Comment: @DarrellHougen `kernel_shape` is `weight tensor's shape`. Consider `kernel_size=(3,3), input_channel=3, gropus=1, filters=64`, the `kernel_size=(3,3)+(1,64)=(3,3,1,64)`, i.e., `[rows(height), cols(width), input_depth, output_depth]` that you have mentioned.